# Integrate $\int \frac{{1}} {{\sin^2 x+\sin2x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have already tried converting $\sin^2(x)$ to the form of $\cos$,  or proceeding by using the completing square form.  Neither of them helped. Substitution won't be possible as the numerator is  simply $1$.

Comment: $$\int\frac{dx}{\sin^2(x)+\sin(2x)}\stackrel{x\mapsto\arctan t}{=}\int\frac{dt}{t^2+2t}=\frac{1}{2}\int\left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t+2}\right)\,dt=C+\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{t}{t+2} $$

Comment: So substitutions **are** possible, and pretty useful, too.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: 
Write the integral as:

$$\int \frac{1}{\sin^2 x + 2 \sin x \cos x } dx\\
= \int \frac{\csc^2 x}{1+2\cot x} dx$$

Now let $\cot(x) = t$.